# Can I increase the value of every item in the list by 1 in every 1 minute in Python?

Tags: python, list, if-statement, time, localtime

I would like to do it by constantly checking local time in my computer. Is there also a way to do it by NOT checking with time of local machine?
I want to also program not execute certain statements during specific times on my local machine. Let's say it does not execute the if statement between 5 and 7 pm.
I would appreciate if someone helped in this topic, please.

Comment: You can use `datetime` module in python. `datetime.now()` will give you the current time which you can compare with 5pm or 7pm as per your requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose I have a list `lst` in which I want to append numbers from 0 to 10, once per minute I can do this.

```
import time

lst = []

for i in range(10):
  lst.append(i)

  time.sleep(60)
```

Now suppose in the example above, you don't want to append the numbers to the list if the current time is between 5 pm and 7 pm use this.

```
import datetime
lst = []

for i in range(10):
  current_hour = datetime.datetime.now().hour
  
  if current_hour >= 17 and current_hour < 19:
    pass

  else:
    lst.append(i)
```

`datetime.datetime.now()` gets you the current datetime. From this, you can use `hour` attribute to get the current hour but the hour is in 24hr format.

---

These two are just arbitrary examples but would help you understand how you can code time into Python.

Comment: I think it needs to be `current_hour < 19` because if the time is for example `19:30` `datetime.datetime.now().hour` would result in `19` and the if statement is true by mistake